# All Sound Quit working

Tags: audio

I'm Running Ubuntu 19.04.
I always let it update as it sees fit. Yesterday, after an update and a reboot, all sound stopped working.

After looking through the internet, and trying lots of suggestions. I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base
sudo apt-get remove --purge pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install alsa-base
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
sudo alsa force-reload
```

I then rebooted. Still no audio. Despite a Dragonfly attached, and a Webcam, it recognizes no devices from the Settings:Sound. No drop down options.
[image]

When I run alsamixer at command prompt and use F6 to select audio device, it sees them correctly, but selecting Dragonfly or any other, still doesn't result in any sound.

[image]

This shows line:out disabled, but it won't let me change any options.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I ended up rolling back kernel.  Did not affect it. 
I examined my apt log and found that before it quit working yesterday, I had installed chrome remote desktop.  That is what caused it.
I uninstalled CRD and rebooted. 
All sound options seen again by the OS and working.

I never would have thought that installing Chrome Remote Desktop would cause that.